# Can a co-manufacture share product samples from company "A" to a potential company?

Tags: branding, trade-secret

Is it legal for the Sales and Marketing team to send new customer samples of products from a different customer?
In contract manufacturing it is come to have may brands that make similar products. When the Sales and marketing team is meeting with new potential customers, they want to give them samples of other products that we produce on site. Not lab samples that have our company log but actual finished product ready to sale.
Can they do that? It feels wrong.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be allowed to do that?

Comment: @bdb484 I think the concern is something like: the manufacturer uses chemical process A to make product B for another company. They want to show off samples of B to demonstrate their proficiency at A to other customers who might use it. But the fact that B uses A is not necessarily publicly known, and revealing it might be a breach of confidence.

Comment: Ah. Generally speaking, I'd say that if there isn't a contract requiring the manufacturer to maintain those confidences, the manufacturer is generally free to share then as widely as it wants. Doing so may be bad business, but it's pretty well protected by the First Amendment.

Comment: Your question is a bit unfocused.  Are the samples presented purchased from a competitor in order to compare your company products to, or were they produced by a contract manufacturer to your specifications?  Either way, there really isn't a compelling public interest reason for the legislature to ban such things.